# An appropriate synonym for "ineligible" in the context

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> Manuscripts published or currently under review elsewhere are ineligible for submission.

Is there a better word to use instead of "ineligible"? Because ineligible seems to be usually used when referring to a person.

EDIT: I'm thinking about some possible synonyms. Is it correct to use "void" instead of "ineligible" in this context?

Comment: I believe that the standard phrase would use things like "will not be considered", "will not be reviewed", "will not be accepted", "are not permitted", and such.

Comment: Who says *ineligible* can only be used with people?  I've never heard of such a rule, and I see *eligible* and *ineligible* used for inanimate objects all the time.  I think your sentence is fine as it is.  *Void* would not make sense here, but if you want an alternative you could use *unacceptable*.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks. What about "invalid"?

Comment: *Invalid* also sounds weird to me in this context.  I wouldn't use it here.

Answer (score 1):

No, ineligible is probably the best word.  "Eligible" basically means "able to be chosen"; it can apply to people or to things.

Void is not a good option.  It means "not having effect," like an invalid (unenforceable) contract.  A published manuscript does not lose its effect.  You might say that *submissions* of published manuscripts are void, but the manuscripts themselves are not void.  They are ineligible.

Answer (score 0):

I work with programmers and they often use 'quantifier' or 'qualifier' for inanimate things. Said that, if you feel (and surprisingly I see that in almost all examples from reputed source, 'in/eligible' is used for living things!) 'ineligible' shouldn't be use, use the word 'qualify'.

So, again, can 'qualifier' be used for non-living things? [Yes, you can](http://www.cquestions.com/2009/06/what-is-qualifier-or-modifier-of-data.html).

> Manuscripts published or currently under review elsewhere are ***un/disqualified*** for submission

This is **one** of the synonyms. There could be some more.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, unqualified too is used only when referring to a person (in reputable sources).

Comment: Not at all, in programming they have integers etc. they are referenced as quantifier, qualifiers etc. So, don't worry. For such things, it's fine.

Comment: "Unqualified" would mean that it's not good enough to be submitted. "disqualified" would be the word you're looking for, really.

Comment: @MaulikV Programmers using "quantifier" and "qualifier" as terms of art does not mean that one can speak of a manuscript being unqualified for submission.  To my ear, unqualified means "not having adequate education, experience, or skills," and "ineligible" is a far better choice in this context than "unqualified."

Comment: Another meaning of unqualified is "not restricted or limited by conditions," which would be closer to (the opposite of) the meaning of "qualifier" used in programming, but which is clearly wrong in this context, as it is not synonymous with "ineligible".

Comment: @phoog nope, you still did not get me. 'qualifier' is the term they use to really mean what qualifies what. Nothing to do with 'terms of art' there. Check the link I provided in the answer.

Comment: @Catija good one. added! :)

Comment: phoog is perfectly right and I said pretty much the same thing. "unqualified" does not work in this situation.

Comment: @MaulikV Whether it is a term of art or not, the meaning of "qualifier" in the page you link to is not relevant to the acceptance or rejection of a submission.  The sense of "qualifier" there is "a word or phrase used to attribute a quality to something."  The related meaning of "unqualified" is "unmodified, not limited, not restricted." This is not a synonym of "ineligible."  The sense of "unqualified" that relates to "ineligible" is "not having the skills, knowledge, or experience needed to do a particular job or activity" (m-w.com) and cannot be applied to a submission.

Comment: @phoog I'm **not** telling that that is *the* word, I said it **can** be used for non-living things. That's what my point is since OP is concerned about whether such words are exclusively used for people.

Comment: @MaulikV the problem is that using the word *in that sense* for an inanimate object is just weird at best and wrong at worst.  It's not the word that has the property of being inapplicable to inanimate objects, it is the meaning.  (And, strictly speaking, it's not the animate/inanimate nature of the object, but its ability to act.  I would balk at speaking of a cat as being qualified or unqualified for an application, too.)